# Creating a dynamic reducer that will change any property of an object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Is this possible?  Say I have a state Object that's a dictionary such as

```
pageDict: {
  someId: {prop1: value1, prop2: value2, etc}
  someId2: {prop1: value1, prop2: value2, etc}
  someId3: {prop1: value1, prop2: value2, etc}
  etc
}
```

Instead of making a reducer that will change prop1.. prop2 .. etc.. I figured I could make a reducer that changes whatever property I want to pass in like this.. but it doesn't like the code.  it starts not liking it as soon as I type action.propertyName... is this not possible?  I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

```
//action
export function setPageProperty( pageId, propertyName, propertyValue ) {
  return { type: types.SET_PAGE_PROPERTY, pageId, propertyName, propertyValue };
}

//reducer
case types.SET_PAGE_PROPERTY: {
  return update( state, { playlistDict: {[ action.pageId ]: { action.propertyName: { $set: action.propertyValue }}}});
}
```

Comment: How about with a single `Object.assign()`  ?

Comment: @FiriceNguyen I've been using immutability-helper as reccommended by React docs.. as changing nested property is a bit of a pain with JS's natural shallow copys.. i can try tho..

Comment: In your update function `action.propertyName` needs to be in square brackets as well, i.e. `[action.propertyName]`

Comment: @AlexYoung thank you!  you saved me so much time instead of writing reducers for every little property